# Search for string based on certain charactertisics

Tags: php, regex

I am working with a really large file that contains strings that I want to extract. The problem is that I don't know what the strings are exactly but I know their characteristics which are:

- 32 characters in length
- Alphanumeric
- The letters in the 32-character-long strings are all lowercase.
- Letters are only from a-f

I think that that the best way to do this would be to use regex, but I can't seem to figure out how.

I found this regex (`^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]{1,10}$`) on a different stack overflow thread which says that it searches for a string between 1-10 characters in length and has at least 1 number and 1 letter. Unfortunately, when I run it, I will not get any results at all so I don't think it would work if I were to modify it.

This is what I am executing as a test before I even try to modify anything:

```
$str = "ok12 aab2 Ab2";
preg_match_all('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]{1,12}$/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Some samples of the 32 character strings:

```
abb660010102020304847bbaedf62622
0987ffbb12444bcdae321123478ebade
```

I even found a regex that should only find strings with the right characteristics but even that will not return any results.

```
$str = "abb660010102020304847bbaedf62622...0987ffbb12444bcdae321123478ebade";
define('R_MD5_MATCH', '/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/i');
preg_match_all(R_MD5_MATCH,$str, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($out);
```

Comment: (not a regexp expert here, but:) with `^` and `$` you ask to match the whole string. When you eliminate them it'll be alright. tested here: https://3v4l.org/KkJo9

Comment: Note that given the code you show, all that text you wrote can be replaced by the single sentence "I need to find all MD5 hashes in a file, what regular expression do I use for that?". And with _that_ question, you can actually find answers on google and stackoverflow already.

Comment: You should take some time and try to learn regex instead of guessing. I see you have this `[a-f0-9]{32}`. To me it looks like it will match any 32 sequential `a-f` or `0-9` characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
/\b[0-9a-f]{32}\b/
```

Which is almost what you found, but this should match both inside a line and by itself, as opposed to yours, that will match only if it's by itself.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aI4Fbu/3)

`^` and `$` are beginning and end of line respectively, while `\b` is a word boundary. This avoids partial matching of longer strings, as that might be undesirable.

A word boundary is basically any non-alphanumeric character, e.g punctuation, spaces, etc.

Comment: Why the word boundary `\b` ?

Comment: @sln to avoid partially matching a longer string, let's say 37 characters long that otherwhise matches the pattern. That would still return the 32 first characters. It might be your desired behaviour, maybe not.

Comment: Yeah, I could see that but the OP is still unclear on boundary, it seems to me. Like is `A<here>a` a boundary ? Also, when you use `\b` it won't match between `a_` , another ambiguity. Since he doesn't seem to know regex at all, I would doubt he knows what a boundary even is.